# Program or script to see hex triplets in their actual color

Tags: colors, hex

I've got a theme file that looks like following:

```
PRIMARY1_COLOR=#7CACDF
PRIMARY2_COLOR=#A5C6E9
PRIMARY3_COLOR=#E2EDF8
SECONDARY1_COLOR=#7CACDF
SECONDARY2_COLOR=#A5C6E9
SECONDARY3_COLOR=#B9D3EE
```

Is there any tool which allows editing such file while displaying actual colors?

Comment: Which OS are your running? Do you have python installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Geany](http://www.geany.org/). It has "Color chooser" button - select your hex code and click on it and you will see the color and will be able to change it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create an HTML file with your favorite text editor and simply load it up your browser. Try this:

```
<style>
.PRIMARY1 { color: #7CACDF }
.PRIMARY2 { color: #A5C6E9 }
...
</style>

<div class="PRIMARY1">PRIMARY1</div>
<div class="PRIMARY2">PRIMARY2</div>
...
```

You can even automatically generate this with some clever find & replace or Excel formulas.